# Mapping slope of an area and returning percent above and below a threshold in R

Tags: r, raster, terrain, r-raster, gis

I am trying to figure our the proportion of an area that has a slope of 0, +/- 5 degrees. Another way of saying it is anything above 5 degrees and below 5 degrees are bad. I am trying to find the actual number, and a graphic.

To achieve this I turned to R and using the Raster package.
Let's use a generic country, in this case, the Philippines

```
{list.of.packages <- c("sp","raster","rasterVis","maptools","rgeos")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)}

library(sp)  # classes for spatial data
library(raster)  # grids, rasters
library(rasterVis)  # raster visualisation
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
```

Now let's get the altitude information and plot the slopes.

```
elevation <- getData("alt", country = "PHL")
x <- terrain(elevation, opt = c("slope", "aspect"), unit = "degrees")
plot(x$slope)
```

[image]
Not very helpful due to the scale, so let's simply look at the Island of Palawan

```
e <- drawExtent(show=TRUE) #to crop out Palawan (it's the long skinny island that is roughly midway on the left and is oriented between 2 and 8 O'clock)
gewataSub <- crop(x,e)
plot(gewataSub, 1)## Now visualize the new cropped object
```

[image: The Island of Palawan]

A little bit better to visualize. I get a sense of the magnitude of the slopes and that with a 5 degree restriction, I am mostly confined to the coast. But I need a little bit more for analysis.

I would like Results to be something to be in two parts:
1. " 35 % (made up) of the selected area has a slope exceeding +/- 5 degrees" or " 65 % of the selected area is within +/- 5 degrees". (with the code to get it)
2. A picture where everything within +/- 5 degrees is one color, call it good or green, and everything else is in another color, call it bad or red.

Thanks

Comment: Well if figured the first part:

    slope <- terrain(elevation, opt = "slope",neighbors = 4)
    a=slope@data@values
    a=subset(a,!is.na(a)) #remove points without elevation (assume water)
    b=subset(a,a<0.05+0.1E-10)  #subset for those that are below 5
    c=subset(a,a>=0.05+0.1E-10)  #subset for those that are above 5
    (prop=length(b)/length(a))   #prop within standards
    (prop2=length(c)/length(a))  #prop above standards

So it looks like about 47% are within +/- 5 degrees, 53% outside

Comment: You can use `paste(round(as.vector(drawExtent()),1), collapse=", ")` and then in your example code something like  `e = extent(116.5, 120.2,  7.6, 11.8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reclassify` from the `raster` package to achieve that. The function assigns each cell value that lies within a defined interval a certain value. For example, you can assign cell values within interval `(0,5]` to value `0` and cell values within the interval `(5, maxSlope]` to value `1`.

```
library(raster)  
library(rasterVis)  

elevation <- getData("alt", country = "PHL")
x <- terrain(elevation, opt = c("slope", "aspect"), unit = "degrees")
plot(x$slope)

e <- drawExtent(show = TRUE)
gewataSub <- crop(x, e)
plot(gewataSub$slope, 1)

m <- c(0, 5, 0,  5, maxValue(gewataSub$slope), 1)
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
rc <- reclassify(gewataSub$slope, rclmat)

levelplot(
  rc,
  margin = F,
  col.regions = c("wheat", "gray"),
  colorkey = list(at = c(0, 1, 2), labels = list(at = c(0.5, 1.5), labels = c("<= 5", "> 5")))
)
```

[image]

After the reclassification you can calculate the percentages:

```
length(rc[rc == 0]) / (length(rc[rc == 0]) + length(rc[rc == 1])) # <= 5 degrees
[1] 0.6628788
length(rc[rc == 1]) / (length(rc[rc == 0]) + length(rc[rc == 1])) # > 5 degrees
[1] 0.3371212
```

Comment: Thank you very much! As I continue to work on my project, I have a follow on question that I may need to start a new post. I would like to add the road network to the map. Then I'd like to shade everything under 5% from the road until it is above 5%, then switch colors. 
thanks again for the help and hopefully the follow-on question is a natural extension of the previous efforts.

Comment: You can get a shapefile of the road network and add it with `layer()` to the levelplot. I am not sure if it is possible to colorize line segments of the shapefile differently. Another approach would be to rasterize the shapefile using `rasterize()` and assign the new raster the values of the rc raster using `mask`. But I suspect just adding the shapefile to the threshold map would be completely sufficient for spatial analysis.

Answer (score 1):

There are no negative slopes, so I assume you want those that are less than 5 degrees

```
library(raster)
elevation <- getData('alt', country='CHE')
x <- terrain(elevation, opt='slope', unit='degrees')

z <- x <= 5
```

Now you can count cells with freq

```
f <- freq(z)
```

If you have a planar coordinate reference system (that is, with units in meters or similar) you can do

```
f <- cbind(f, area=f[,2] * prod(res(z)))
```

to get areas. But for lon/lat data, you would need to correct for different sized cells and do

```
a <- area(z)
zonal(a, z, fun=sum)
```

And there are different ways to plot, but the most basic one

```
plot(z)
```