# Shade distance away from a road network that is within a slope threshold

Tags: r, geospatial, raster

I started a project that is trying to find how far I can drive off a road assuming I am limited by roads, slope, and vegetation. I tried approaching the problem sequentially, but I am running into more problems than I can solve so I'll add everything in this post.

My vehicle can't drive at a more than a 5 degree slope, so my first attempt was to [find all the terrain that is <= 5 degrees.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675851/mapping-slope-of-an-area-and-returning-percent-above-and-below-a-threshold-in-r)

Thanks to @Christopher-Stephan, I have the following picture. 
 [image: Area that is steeper than 5 degrees of slope]

I cannot seem to find prior work or a post that addresses what I am trying to do so I'll describe it.

Given an area when I am on a road in a car, in this case Palawan, I'm trying to see how far I can drive off-road before the slope is steeper than 5 degrees (very important) or I run into a jungle (less important).

I am thinking now that I have the slope within 5 degrees, I plot the roads and somehow shade an adjacent box that is less than 5 degrees. Once the slope is more than 5, shade it a different color. (the output being this graphic).

Then I would just need to find the proportion of the area that is within each shaded region (assuming you find p, the other is 1-p).

The code for the picture is below

```
library(raster)  
library(rasterVis)  
elevation <- getData("alt", country = "PHL")
x <- terrain(elevation, opt = c("slope", "aspect"), unit = "degrees")
e <- drawExtent(show = TRUE)
gewataSub <- crop(x, e)
m <- c(0, 5, 0,  5, maxValue(gewataSub$slope), 1)
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
rc <- reclassify(gewataSub$slope, rclmat)
levelplot(rc, margin = F,  col.regions = c("wheat", "gray"),  colorkey = list(at = c(0, 1, 2), labels = list(at = c(0.5, 1.5), labels = c("<= 5", "> 5"))))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the road network as a shapefile from http://philgis.org/country-basemaps/roads and add it to the levelplot. From there I do not understand exactly what your expected result would be.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(rgdal)

elevation <- getData("alt", country = "PHL")
x <- terrain(elevation, opt = c("slope", "aspect"), unit = "degrees")
plot(x$slope)

e <- drawExtent(show = TRUE)
gewataSub <- crop(x, e)
plot(gewataSub$slope, 1)

m <- c(0, 5, 0,  5, maxValue(gewataSub$slope), 1)
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
rc <- reclassify(gewataSub$slope, rclmat)

roads = readOGR("/Users/christopherstephan/Downloads", layer = "roads")

levelplot(
  rc,
  margin = F,
  col.regions = c("wheat", "gray"),
  colorkey = list(at = c(0, 1, 2), labels = list(
    at = c(0.5, 1.5), labels = c("<= 5", "> 5")
  ))
) + layer(sp.polygons(roads))
```

[image]